# Could there ever be a reliable In-Memory Service Bus in a C# solution using the CQRS pattern?

Tags: c#, messaging, cqrs

I was reading the book entitled [Architecting for the Enterprise in .NET 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735685355) that teaches the new emerging patters, like CQRS and Event Sourcing. 
I found in the demo apps from the book an implementation of an "in-memory bus". I know that a physical queue can bring reliability to a service bus implemented in a CQRS solution, but is there a way that an In-Memory written in pure C# be reliable and crash resilient?

Please, help me reformulate my question if needed. I am from Paraguay an my English needs a lot of work. Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: "In-memory" and "crash resilient" are unlikely to be ever satisfied together... Note that your post is too broad for SO.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov, what does SO stands for?

Comment: @Narvalex SO stands for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov) said: "In-memory" and "crash resilient" are unlikely to be ever satisfied together...
So the answer is No.